# What is the syntax/signature of a Objective-C method that returns a block without typedef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

I defined a block that takes an `NSString` and returns a `NSURL` for that string:

```
id (^)(id obj)
```

I've used `typedef` to make it a block with a name:

```
typedef id (^URLTransformer)(id);
```

And the following method does not work:

```
+ (URLTransformer)transformerToUrlWithString:(NSString *)urlStr
{
    return Block_copy(^(id obj){
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:NSString.class])
        {
            NSString *urlStr = obj;
            return [NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
        return nil; // **THIS LINE FAILS**
    });
}
```

Error:

> Return type 'void *' must match previous return type 'id' when block
>   literal has unspecified explicit return type

My question is:
1. how to correctly implement the method
2. how to implement the method without typedef URLTransformer?

Thanks

Comment: What does your code do with the method's `urlStr` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

You can either cast it to `id` or add type to block. I asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122723/why-the-type-of-nil-is-not-id-but-void) before and quote from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17128800/642626)

> The correct way to remove that error is to provide a return type for
>   the block literal:

```
id (^block)(void) = ^id{
    return nil; 
};
```

in your case

```
+ (URLTransformer)transformerToUrlWithString:(NSString *)urlStr
{
    return Block_copy(^id(id obj){ // id here
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:NSString.class])
        {
            NSString *urlStr = obj;
            return [NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
        return nil; // id here
    });
}
```

or

```
+ (URLTransformer)transformerToUrlWithString:(NSString *)urlStr
{
    return Block_copy(^(id obj){
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:NSString.class])
        {
            NSString *urlStr = obj;
            return [NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
        return (id)nil; // **THIS LINE FAILS**
    });
}
```

2.

To return block without typedef you can use similar syntax to return function pointer

```
+ (id (^)(id))transformerToUrlWithString:(NSString *)urlStr;
```

You can check more example from [here](https://github.com/robb/Underscore.m/blob/development/Underscore/Underscore+Functional.h).

PS: You should avoid `Block_copy` in ObjC code, use `[block copy]`.

PS2: You mush be using ARC (otherwise so many leaks) and you don't need to copy block explicitly (in 99% of the cases, which includes this one).

PS3: Your should avoid `id` as much as possible, so your block should be `typedef NSURL *(^URLTransformer)(NSString *);`

Comment: Hi it says 'Cast of block pointer type 'id(^)(__strong id)' to C pointer type 'const void *' requires a bridged cast, and if I do not use Block_copy it works with [... copy].

Comment: @hzxu what is your Xcode/Clang version? you can also cast `nil`. e.g. `return (id)nil;`

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid `typedef` like this:

```
@interface Blah : NSObject
+(id (^)(id)) blockret;
@end

@implementation Blah
+(id (^)(id)) blockret {
    return ^(id obj) {
        return @"helo";
    };
}
@end
```

The type of your block is `id (^)(id)` - that's what goes into parentheses after the plus.