# Is return (id)nil; valid?

Tags: objective-c

I want to return `nil` from a function that expects to get `id`. The compiler complains about this when I'm writing blocks. So, is it ok to `return (id)nil;`? Or am I misunderstanding something about what `nil` and `id` are?

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: it says "Incompatible block pointer types sending `'void *(^)(void)'` to parameter of type `'id (^)()'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is valid. `nil` "should" be type of `id` (actually it is `void *` for some reason) but it is totally safe to cast `nil` to `id`. Similarly apply to `0` and `NULL` (they all just `0`). And send message to `0` result defined behaviour (nop) so everything is fine.

I have the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122723/why-the-type-of-nil-is-not-id-but-void) about return `nil` in block and this is quote from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17128800/642626)
:

> You're using an inferred return type for your block literal, but you
>   don't have to.
>
> The correct way to remove that error is to provide a return type for
>   the block literal:

```
id (^block)(void) = ^id{
    return nil;
};
```

Comment: how do I specify the return type when I'm providing the block in-line to another function call?

Comment: @Claudiu instead of `^{ return nil;}`, do `^id{ return nil;}`